# import javafx.application.Application; not working in Eclipse (Ubuntu 18.04.1)

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Today the whole day I tried to wrap my head around how to use the import JavaFX.application.Application and how to make it work. But I failed. I tried on 3 different IDEs , NetBeans, eclipse and vsCode but none worked. Watched about 30 videos tried everything available on the internet but still unable to figure out how to include the import statement and make it work. Some solutions are too advance that are beyond my understanding.

Can someone please walk me through the process and point me to a resource where I can learn how to use Eclipse IDE. For the future I would like to stick to Eclipse.

My OS- Ubuntu 18.04.2
Eclipse version is 2019 (latest) my entire day is wasted on figuring out how to make import javafx work.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found the solution to this problem.

I'm sharing the solution so that others facing this problem do not have to go through the same frustation.

Steps:

Install openjfx on your system. It is easy to do so not including the steps. Once installed it should be available in /usr/share/openjfx/lib)

1) Go to project's Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Modulepath --> Add Library --> User Library (Create a new user library and name it JavaFX11 and add all javaFX jars in it)

2) Add the below lines under VM arguments in Run Configuration

```
--module-path C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\javafx-sdk-11\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls
```

Your project should run. Though I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 the above arguments worked for me.